# Map is not working in Samsung Galaxy tablet in emulator

Tags: google-maps, android

My application is developed with maps and some other listviews.

When i removed

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

from manifest file the app is working fine, but when i add this in manifest, i am getting

```
Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY
```

error, how to resolve this to work the app in galaxy tablet emulator

Answer (score 3):

You should use an Android Build with Google APIs. Right click your project > Properties > Android, select an item that has "Google APIs" in the target name. Be sure to select the version you need.

Google Maps require the Android Library that contains Google APIs. So if your using Android SDK 2.3... then you should choose "Google APIs 2.3".

[image]

If you can't find one then you should download it using your Android SDK Manager.

[image]

Select whichever version you need:

[image]

Comment: yes it is there, project build target is 2.3.3 Google APIs, but my running device target is Samsung galaxy tablet...

Comment: what Android version is your Samsung Galaxy running ?

Comment: if it is not there for your device then you can install it

Comment: You have to run an GoogleAPI Emulator too, in order to have access to the maps

Comment: yup I agree with @Cata , but you will still need to download first the Android SDK that says "Google APIs", setup your emulator (making sure to pick "Google APIs" in the SDK version), change your project's Android SDK library to point to the Android SDK with "Google API's" too

Answer (score 0):

you should check your AVD is its simple or Google API

because Google MAP works only in Google API.

Comment: when i updated the AVD there are no tablet devices with google map APIs,

Comment: which api available can u list out that.