# Java The import com.google cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android

I am working on building and running an android application in Eclipse. I have successfully installed the Android kit, along with the google api via the ADT. I downloaded a sample google map android application to run. very simple file. However, my lib references don't seem to be working fine. Even though in the manifest file, the google map api is referenced, my application is not able to resolve the reference

any idea what I need to do next to get the referencing issues resolved please?

Comment: what Eclipse version? what ADT version? and is the Google Maps API jar showing in your android dependencies list in the Eclipse project?

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10040928/1289716) answer

Comment: Refer this link , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777291/package-com-google-android-maps-cannot-be-resolved/11777410#11777410

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to download google apis for a particular api level through android sdk manager.

[image]

**Select that google api as project build target.**

[image]

Comment: In case this helps anyone else, the solution for me was that the project's target had magically changed from "Google APIs" to "Android 2.2". Re-setting it fixed this.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse you should be able to configure the project's classpath to point to the libraries in question. Assuming you have them and the plugin. See the SDK Manager if you don't have them.

Answer (score 0):

If **selecting the particular APIs** is not working try the following:

- project->clean
- right click on project->Android Tools-> Fix Project Properties

Comment: Already did that a couple of times and it did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have added

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

line into the AndroidManifest.xml as a child of  `<application>` tag