# how to use google map in android 2.3 application

Tags: android, api, android-intent, sdk

While I am trying to extend my class to `MapActivity` it is show error like *"no suggestion available"*. I had installed all the google apis.

Comment: please post your source code.

Comment: Refer this link, it will help 


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806937/java-the-import-com-google-cannot-be-resolved/11807878#11807878

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to set the your project `Target` as per below image -

[image: Screenshot]

And, have a look at [Google Mapview tutorial](http://codemagician.wordpress.com/2010/05/06/android-google-mapview-tutorial-done-right/) Don't forget to create an `AVD` as per same project creation with `Google-API` like below one

[image]

Comment: public class Google_AndroidActivity extends MapActivity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

Comment: @Vishnu What's with this? It seems perfect. Having any trouble with this?

Comment: Yeah, thanks, now working.,but i have one doubt, if we do the steps, like, Project-> properties-> Android->Google Apis, then the project will be in what version? , i need in version 2.3. how is it possible?

Comment: If you need versions from 2.3. You've to download it using SDK manager in android. As per in [this](http://www.mkyong.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/android-sdk-manager.png) image it showing the android version `2.3.3`as API level 10. You should download this one. Then only you can create an avd with version of `2.3.3` and run your project with it.

Comment: yeah ok...thanks, so version depends up on the API level we are using? is it right?

Comment: yes... and also i need to use Google map in existing projects, so is it possible?

Comment: @Vishnu Yes. Its possible the same way you've to set the project build target with `Google-API` and for `AVD`'s also.