# the import of com google android gms appstate cannot be resolved after update sdk using eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

After update sdk to version 6 api23 cannot compile the program in eclipse with error:

> the import of com google android gms appstate cannot be resolved.

While it was perfectly OK the moment just before i did update the SDK.

There is the same situation found on stackoverview but it was solved using android studio gradle and not using eclipse.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15990075/the-import-com-google-android-gms-cannot-be-resolved

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11806937/java-the-import-com-google-cannot-be-resolved

Comment: Intellij Amiya thanks for your reponse. Already did what mentioned there before I ask here but not fixed. After search i think i know the problem is because the appstatemanager is deprecated on api23

Comment: It can be fixed at android studi gradle by compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appstate:6.5.87' but because i'm using eclipse how can i acjieve the same fix?

Comment: Well in fact the problem is on deprecated class on new api. Waiting for fix from google team on gamehelper java

Comment: I fix it now. Just download the newest gamehelper java from github which implement the new play service api after the old one was deprecated. Well i learn it the hard way